# Android api 21/22 android version 5 video playing problems, video playing throws error Can't play video

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, mp4, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Here is my code. When I run this app on android nexus 4 API 22, it throws me error saying "Can't play this video." However, the audio of video plays. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

video file is in mp4 format.

```
package com.example.videoplayinginandroid5

import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.MediaController
import android.widget.VideoView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var playBtn : Button = findViewById(R.id.play_video)
        var videoView : VideoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view)

        var videoPath = "android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.personal_intro
        var uri = Uri.parse(videoPath)
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri)


        playBtn.setOnClickListener {
            videoView.start()
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any logcat available?

Comment: yes I get these errors E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-38)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-38

Comment: @Kaustubh.P.N  did you solve it?  im getting the same error...